# SP2010 Calendar Event removal via Outlook Email Cancellation

Tags: 2010, outlook, sharepoint-calendar

I've enabled incoming email for my SP calendar and have that working just fine.  If I create a meeting through outlook, it populates my SP calendar and my Outlook calendar.  If I then cancel the meeting through Outlook, the event is removed from my Outlook calendar, but it is not removed from the SP calendar.  Instead, the SP calendar displays the message:

> "Cancelled: Meeting Title"

Is there a way to have the SP calendar automatically remove cancelled events, whether through a setting or programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A SharePoint calendar is still fundamentally a list behind the scenes. Why not simply create a list item workflow for the list and place an "item updated" check in place?

If the calendar item title contains "Cancelled" then you can add a task to delete the item automatically. Alternatively, remove all read permissions for standard users so that you can still view the calendar entry retrospectively as an admin.